# cannot send email using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I was trying sent email using PHP CodeIgniter framework. after i uploaded that file into my browser it didn't show me any error. it said:"Your email was sent successfully". But i didn't get any email in my email account. I could not figure out what was the problem. I am using CodeIgniter version 2.1.3. can anyone please help me. I am new in PHP. Thank You.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
class Email extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from('hasib32@gmail.com', 'Hasan Hasibul');
        $this->email->to('riar32@gmail.com');
        $this->email->subject('email test');
        $this->email->message('testing the email class. email sent');
        if($this->email->send()){
            echo"Your email was sent successfully";
        }else
        {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check the spam box?

Comment: If according to codeigniter the message was sent, that means the system has accepted the message for delivery. So it is not a php / codeigniter problem anymore but probably a system configuration problem. You should start with checking the logs.

Comment: yes.i cheeked spam box. but nothing there.

Comment: If you are testing the functionality locally in your machine, sometime s the problem seems to be the nameserver for your ISP. You can check your mailq in your machine. Hint: in linux operating system, just type mailq in terminal and check it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => '...@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => '....',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE

    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $email_setting  = array('mailtype'=>'html');
    $this->email->initialize($email_setting);
    $email_body ="<div>hello world</div>";
    $this->email->from('...@gmail.com', 'shahriar');

    $list = array('...@gmail.com');
    $this->email->to($list);
    $this->email->subject('Testing Email');
    $this->email->message($email_body);

    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();

    }
```

this works for me. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Its because you don't have mail server setup in your localhost. You can either setup it or you can use your gmail account to send your mail like this-

```
$config = Array(
      ‘protocol’ => ‘smtp’,
      ‘smtp_host’ => ‘ssl://smtp.googlemail.com’,
      ‘smtp_port’ => 465,
      ‘smtp_user’ => ‘myusername@gmail.com’,
      ‘smtp_pass’ => ‘mypassword’,
    );

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->from('hasib32@gmail.com', 'Hasan Hasibul');
$this->email->to('riar32@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('email test');
$this->email->message('testing the email class. email sent');
if($this->email->send()){
    echo"Your email was sent successfully";
} else {
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check e-mail server in the mail queue. probably waiting.